# Angular display scopes in Eclipse outline explorer

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs, outline

I have a lot of Angular functions like this in each controller:

```
$scope.loginUser = function() {
```

Problem is that these scope functions are not displayed in class outline, it means that is not displayed structure of controller like this:

```
-Controller 
 - loginUser
 - anotherFunction
```

Is there any plugin or extension for Eclipse which can help me to get code structure?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suggest you to install AngularJS Eclipse https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse. It provides an Angular Explorer which display Modules, Controllers, Directives, etc